# Interact with SQLite database in JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I have an existing SQLite database that I want to use for a really simple website I'm building. What is the best way to integrate this? My goal is to click a button on my page which triggers a JQuery function where I can call to the SQLite DB to get a specific row.

Javascript/JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#get-city").click(function() {
    var city = '<p class="city">' + getCity() + '</p>'
    var searchBtn = document.getElementById("city-form")
    searchBtn.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', city)
    return false
  });
});

function getCity() {
  // where I would make the call to SQLite DB
}
```

I am using `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to add the JQuery library if that makes a difference.

Comment: you really can't do that from a web browser.

Comment: I have been working on the same type of project where I successfully used Python and Matplotlib for simplicity. Worked fine, but the Java graphs are much more interactive and advanced. I have yet to find any direct method in Java, however you can dump to a temporary .csv with Flask, then import from there. I'm not sure if I can post 3rd party sites, but if you search something to that extent, you will find your solution.